# How to input two numbers in Main using Scanner and make it work with a method (Ascending order java)?

Tags: java, for-loop, methods, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to make this program that will print out numbers in ascending order between two input numbers. I made it work as a method and I can call the method in Main, but what I really want to do is to input the two numbers in Main and not in the method.

So something like this:

System.out.println(”Two numbers in ascending order”);

(input two numbers in console)

And then after this, call the method that will print in ascending order between the chosen numbers of Main.

I’m new to this and i’ve tried several things, but I can’t seem to figure out what to do. Would appreciate som help.

This is how the code looks now.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AscendingOrder {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // calling method

        int ascending1 = ascending();
    }

    public static int ascending() {

        int min;
        int max;
        int total = 0;

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Two numbers in ascending order");
        min = sc.nextInt();
        max = sc.nextInt();

        for (int i = min; i < max + 1; i++) {
            System.out.print(i + " ");
            total += i;

        }
        return total;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass in the two inputs as *parameters* to your method, something like :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println("Two numbers in ascending order");
     int min = sc.nextInt();
     int max = sc.nextInt();

     int ascending1 = ascending(min, max);
     System.out.println(ascending1);
}
```

And now :

```
public static int ascending(int min, int max) {
    int total = 0;
    for (int i = min; i < max + 1; i++) {
       System.out.print(i + " ");
       total += i;
     }
     return total;
}
```

Notice that now the definition of `ascending()` takes in two *parameters* of type `int`. The values are passed from the main method to the method.

Answer (score 0):

You can input the numbers in the `main` method and then pass them to another method:

```
public class AscendingOrder {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Two numbers in ascending order");
        int min = sc.nextInt();
        int max = sc.nextInt();

        int ascending1 = ascending(min, max);
    }

    public static int ascending(int min, int max) {
        int total = 0;

        for (int i = min; i < max + 1; i++) {
            System.out.print(i + " ");
            total += i;
        }
        return total;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read the command line arguments or place the scanner in main function and pass the arguments

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AscendingOrder {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Entered first number is: "+args[0]);  
        System.out.println("Entered Secomd number is: "+args[1]);  
        int ascending1 = ascending(Integer.parseInt(args[0]),Integer.parseInt(args[1]));
    }

    public static int ascending(int min,int max) {

        int total = 0;

        for (int i = min; i < max + 1; i++) {
            System.out.print(i + " ");
            total += i;

        }
        return total;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the numbers in main method and sort them in the main method itself. Java 8 makes it so easy with streams.

```
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {

    Framework.startup( );

    Scanner sc = new Scanner( System.in );
    System.out.println( "Two numbers in ascending order" );
    int num1= sc.nextInt( );
    int num2= sc.nextInt( );

    Arrays.asList( num1, num2).stream( ).sorted( ).forEach( System.out::println );
    }
```

Comment: Probably `IntStream.range(sc.nextInt(), sc.nextInt()).forEach(System.out::println)` would be better in this case. This will avoid the need for sorting.